# How to find the last row without '-' in it

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe `df`. In every column eventually the values are '-' until the end of the dataframe. I would like to find the final row where there is no '-' value.  How can I do that?

```
df.isin(['-'])
```

gives me a dataframe full of Trues and Falses. So I want the last row that only has False in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`df.tail(1)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.tail.html) to pick the last row:

```
df[df.isin(['-'])].tail(1)
```

To get the last row with `False` use `~` Not operator:

```
df[~df.isin(['-'])].tail(1)
```

Comment: Oh I see. Thanks! Very simple now you show me. I guess I want the opposite in fact (just updated the question) but that is simple from here.

Comment: @fomin Updated my answer. Please check.

Comment: Is that the last row with *only* False in it? That is with no Trues at all.

Comment: Yes. So you negate the condition. This will give you rows which don't have `-` in them. Then use `tail(1)` to pick the last row.

Comment: Should `df[~df.isin(['-']) & ~df.isnull()]`only give me rows that contain neither '-' not 'NaN'?

Comment: @fomin Yes exactly.